# How to compare strings that have an ampersand in them in PowerShell

Tags: string, powershell, compare

I am using PowerShell to compare two strings that have an ampersand (&) in them (i.e. the string "Policies & Procedures").

No matter what I try, I cannot get these strings to match. I have tried trimmed the strings to get rid of an extra white spaces. I have tried wrapping the the string in both single and double quotes (and a combination of both):

```
"Policies & Procedures"
'Policies & Procedures'
"'Policies & Procedures'"
```

The code I am using to compare the strings is:

```
if ($term1 -eq $term2) {
  do something
}
```

Inspecting the strings visually - they are identical, however the if statement never evaluates to true. Is there a way to compare these two strings so that it does evaluate to true?

**EDIT**

The context in which I am doing this string compare is looking for a term name in a taxonomy for a SharePoint site. Here is the code I am using:

```
function getTerm($termName) {

  foreach($term in $global:termset.Terms) {
    $termTrimmed = $term.Name.trim()
    Write-Host "term name = $termTrimmed" -foregroundcolor cyan
    if ($termTrimmed -eq $termName) {
      return $term
    } 
  }
  return null
}
```

I have printed both term.Name and termName to the screen and they are identical. If there is no ampersand in the string, this function works. If there is an ampersand this function fails. This is how I know the ampersand is the problem.

Comment: Just tried the below code and it returned `$true` as expected, can you show the code that is generating your strings?

    `$term1 = 'Policies & Procedures'`


    `$term2 = 'Policies & Procedures'`

    `$term1 -eq $term2`

Comment: same thing, returns `$True` for me.

Comment: Ampersand is [not a special character in PowerShell strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules), what makes you call it out as the particular thing causing the problem?

Comment: I don't think my question should be downgraded as it does reveal a difference between ampersands

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a [known quirk](https://statto1974.wordpress.com/2013/01/14/the-tale-of-two-ampersands-in-a-taxonomy-term/):

> There are two types of ampersands that you need to be aware of when
>   playing with SharePoint Taxonomy
>
> Our favorite and most loved
>
> - `&` ASCII Number: `38`
>
> And the impostor
>
> - `＆` ASCII Number: `65286`
>
> After reading [this article](http://nickhobbs.wordpress.com/2012/03/29/sharepoint-2010-managed-metadata-converts-ampersand-and-double-quotes-to-unicode/) by [Nick Hobbs](http://nickhobbs.wordpress.com/), it became apparent
>   that when you create a term it replaces the `38` ampersand with a
>   `65286` ampersand.
>
> This then becomes a problem if you want to do a comparison with your
>   original source (spreadsheet, database, etc) as they are no longer the
>   same.
>
> As detailed in Nick’s article, you can use the
>   `TaxonomyItem.NormalizeName` method to create a "Taxonomy" version of
>   your string for comparison:

Try this (not tested on real SharePoint):

```
function getTerm($termName)
{
  foreach($term in $global:termset.Terms) {
    $termNormalized = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TaxonomyItem]::NormalizeName($term.Name)
    if ($termNormalized -eq $termName) {
      return $term
    } 
  }
  return null
}
```

Comment: It is difficult to see `65286` as an `ASCII` code since ASCII is a 7-bit encoding. The `65286` value is a Unicode codepoint for a FULLWIDTH AMPERSAND.

Comment: This is a much more elegant solution than mine. Thanks for posting this!

Answer (score 2):

After converting both strings to char arrays and comparing the unicode value of the ampersands the problem is revealed. The ampersand used in the search string has a value of 38 while the ampersand returned from the SharePoint term store has a value of 65286 (called a full ampersand although looks identical  to a regular ampersand on screen).

The solution was to write my own string comparison function and take into account the differences in the ampersand values. Here is the code:

```
function getTerm($termName) {

  $searchChars = $termName.toCharArray()
  $size = $searchChars.Count;
  foreach($term in $global:termset.Terms) {
    $match = $True
    $chars = $term.Name.trim().toCharArray()
    if ($size -eq $chars.Count) {
      for ($i = 0; $i -lt $size; $i++) {
        if ($searchChars[$i] -ne $chars[$i]) {
          # handle the difference between a normal ampersand and a full width ampersand
          $charCode1 = [int] $searchChars[$i]
          $charCode2 = [int] $chars[$i]
          if ((($charCode1 -eq 38) -or ($charCode1 -eq 65286 )) -and (($charCode2 -eq 38) -or ($charCode2 -eq 65286 ))) {
            continue
          } else {
            $match = $False
            break
          }
        }
      }
    } else {
      $match = $False
    }
    if ($match -eq $True) {
      return $term
    }
  }
  return $null
}
```