# Comparing String that had ampersand in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to compare two string

```
"Food & Beverages" == "Food ＆ Beverages"
```

and result I am getting is false. This is because the ascii value of the character 7 is different in
& ASCII Number: 38

＆ ASCII Number: 65286

One value is from database and other is from file. is there a way to compare these two string?

in powershell they are asking to normalise the string.

[How to compare strings that have an ampersand in them in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40938055/how-to-compare-strings-that-have-an-ampersand-in-them-in-powershell)

Is there similar thing available in flutter?

Comment: ASCII defines values only in the range [0, 127].  The value you're seeing is the value of a UTF-16 codepoint.  For reference, 65286 (U+FF06) is `FULLWIDTH AMPERSAND`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to remove these characters before you compare two string.

So something like:

```
String cleanString(String s) {
  return s.replaceAll(RegExp('[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]*'), '');
}

bool compare(String s1, String s2) {
  return cleanString(s1) == cleanString(s2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should replace the characters before the comparison. I think this is the best way,